# Advanced htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect all links with this format
    https://besthost.tn/aze/viewticket.php?tid=VARIABLE1&c=VARIABLE2
to
    https://besthost.tn/client-2/?ccce=viewticket&tid=VARIABLE1&c=VARIABLE2

the VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2 must be inchanged while the redirection.
thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also `tid=VARIABLE1&c=VARIABLE2` is same in both URLs

Comment: no , they are different . exemple : http://besthost.tn/aze/viewticket.php?tid=324102&c=XKAVJ92r

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /viewticket.php\?tid=([^&]+)&c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /client-2/?ccce=viewticket&tid=%1&c=%2 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: i placed your code in the top of my htaccess file ( in public_html) .
i can not get redirection with http://besthost.tn/aze/viewticket.php?tid=324102&c=XKAVJ92r

Answer (score 0):

This will work from the root and identify '/aze/viewticket.php' and then the tid=X&C=X pattern for redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aze/viewticket\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tid=(.+)&c=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client-2/?ccce=viewticket&tid=%1&c=%2 [L,R=301]
```

The R=301 part indicates a 301 'permanent' redirect which will be cached by the browser and is required if this is a permanent change in your website (for performance reasons).

Comment: i placed your code in the top of my htaccess file ( in public_html) . i can not get redirection with besthost.tn/aze/viewticket.php?tid=324102&c=XKAVJ92r